# Поместить Gutenberg редактор в метабокс

Tags: php, wordpress, gutenberg

Господа форумчане! В моих проектах стала часто возникать потребность в добавлении кастомного контента на страницы Категорий и Архива постов. Эту задачу я решаю таким образом ---

1. Создаётся новый тип записей к примеру "Category pages", который скрывается от индексации и выдачи.
2. В term.php добавляется селект в котором можно выбрать контент какой из "Category pages" выводить в архиве терма. Для страницs таксономии процедура аналогична, только мета бокс селекта выводится на theme_option

Так вот, решение хотя рабочее но костыльное и как по мне не красивое, и не совсем интуитивно понятное заказчикам. Потому моя идея:
**помещать Getenberd редактор в большой метабокс, который потом выводить как в отдельную theme_option, так и на страницу редактирования term.php. После чего сохранять его контент в term_meta или theme_option так как это делается в постах из post_content**

Кто то может подсказать ключ к решению этой мудрёной но по сути очень практичной и полезной задачки?

Comment: Не надо никаких theme_option и кастомных типов. Достаточно кастомного поля. Даже плагины для этого были. На худой конец - виджеты.

Comment: ну так мне и нужно кастомное поле, но чтобы в нём был доступен функционал блоков Gutenberg, ибо я регистрирую кастомные блоки для редактора, и часть этих блоков должна выводится в уникальных комбинациях на страницах (таксономий/термов). Полями типо rich-text или костыляниями с десятком кастомных полей на 1 квадратную категорию не выход. @SeVlad

Comment: см напр https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/gutenberg-acf/

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли, регистрировать блоки в гутенберг я умею. Мой вопрос в том - чтобы добавить редактор (целиком) в метабокс на кастомную страницу админки, там где редактора по дефолту нет

Comment: Или ты меня не понял.. Зачем вообще  создавать отдельную страницу админки, если и логичнее и проще добавить кастомное поле с гутером (или изменить родную форму описания) в рубрику?

Comment: Так "добавить кастомное поле с гутером (или изменить родную форму описания) в рубрику" я в целом именно это и имел в виду, кастомную страницу админки привёл просто в пример ибо имея редактор в кастомном поле мы можем всунуть его куда угодно. Мой вопрос в том, как сделать такое поле, чтобы внутри него был редактор или как Вы сказали - изменить родную форму описания? В ACF есть такая функция?